# Office 365 for Mac - Changing default attachment opening and saving behaviour

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, office365, save-as

Situation:
MAC User opens a word doc attachment from outlook, makes edits, forgets he has never saved-as, then saves or quicksaves, quits, reboots MAC.

Outcome:
attachments opened in word exist in the Outlook temporary folder, but are editable and saveable.  This folder is typically emptied on reboot.  The user has lost his work.

Question:
How can I stop my users doing this other than physically training them to immediately save-as?  Possible approaches:

- PREFERRED SOLUTION: Make attachments opened in word read only or protected view (forcing a save-as to edit)
- Pop up a warning if saving to a temp folder
- Stop the temp folder deleting on restart (not an ideal solution)
- Make attachments save to a non-temp folder automatically when opened in word

Can I do any of these on Mac? I'm a windows power user and the adjustment to Mac has been brutal to say the least. Help a fellow out!

Comment: Send the Word file in a ZIP archive? The Zip will be expanded on opening from the e-mail client, but the Word file will not be, user then opens a file that is saved on their hard drive.

Comment: Unfortunately the emails are external and we have no control over their content or format

Comment: My Word/Excel attachments are opened in read-only mode when I open them in my Outlook for Mac. There may be somthing wrong with your Office for Mac(add-in?). Please refer to this thread:https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office-for-mac-protected-view/d4172b26-78d0-4522-a761-7318d6a47f2e

Comment: It's possible, though I can see from googling around that LOTS of people seem to have the same problem (no solutions though!).  Any ideas what to do?